# Exiting Salesforce

Tags: data, data-extract

Our organisation has made a decision to stop using Salesforce which means i need to extract all of the data from the system.

I have ran the Data Extract funcationality, however this extracts all of the data based on the "module" the information is stored, however what we want to do is extract the data based on case number.

we want in each file
- Case Information
- Person
- Description information
- Case Team
- Case Notes
- Activity History
- Emails
- Attachments
and finally Case history.

Does anyone know how this can be done in one file based on Case number not "module"?

apparently this specific requirement can be done using SOQL (Database.Query()) to fetch the data based on the case number, however this is outside my skill level, any suggestions/tips?

Answer (score 0):

Using Data Loader tool, this will not be possible. Extracting entire data using data loader in separate CSVs will also be a suggestion from my side, to keep your data stored in one place for later reference.

As far as your particular requirement is concerned, this can only be done by getting a developer's help, who will write some batch class to process your all desired cases one by one or may be in a batch of 100-200 records, and have your data extract files attached to that particular case record, so that you can download it finally from there or even extract it using data loader.

Please go through the below link to get an idea of the code, which can help getting all data related to one case in single excel spreadsheet. 
http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/export-excel-multiple-worksheets-visualforce/

Hope this help :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[CopyStorm Dump](https://www.capstorm.com/dump) is a free app and can pull entire Salesforce org data into csv files. You might need some help from computer savvy person - try first to watch their instructions videos.